# How to create a rails checkbox within a form using an enum that saves as an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble figuring this out in my beginning rails journey. There really isn't too much documentation about this so appreciate the help!

I have a model called Documents where I've got the following enum for the :target_industries attribute (:target_industries is a string)

```
enum target_industries:{
        'Automotive':0,
        'Business Services':1,
        'Construction':2,
        'Consumer Goods':3,
        'Consumer Services':4,
        'Distribution':5,
        'Education':6,
        'Energy & Utilities':7}
```

In my Documents controller I allow that to be an array:

```
params.require(:documents).permit(:target_industries => [])
```

I want to reference these values in a rails form for the Documents/new form and save multiple :target_industries as an array. How would I do that? This doesn't save anything but I'm seeing it correctly rendered in the view:

```
<% Documents.target_industries.each do |key, val| %>
      <%#= form.check_box val %>
      <%= check_box_tag :target_industries, {multiple:true}, val %>
      <%= form.label key %>
    <%end %>
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you show the controller code and server log for the request when you select multiple values?

Comment: Can we see model and controller please? Would it be better to have the industries as a separate model? and a join table?